# Extracting a substring from a variable using bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bash variable with value something like this:

```
10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0
```

There are no spaces within value. This value can be very long or very short. Here pairs such as `65:3.0` exist. I know the value of a number from the first part of pair, say `65`. I want to extract the number `3.0` or pair `65:3.0`. I am not aware of the position (offset) of `65`.

I will be grateful for a bash-script that can do such extraction. Thanks.

Comment: Can `65` appear more than once in the value? Could there also be (e.g. `165:4.0`)?

Comment: How big is 'very long'?  Megabytes, gigabytes, bigger? Is it all on one line?  Is that format renegotiable?  Are the keys always in sorted order (as they are in the example)?

Comment: It is around 10000 key-value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

Probably awk is the most straight-forward approach:

```
awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{print $2}' <<< "$var"
3.0
```

Or to get the pair:

```
$ awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65' <<< "$var"
65:3.0
```

Comment: Yup, that's how to do it. +1.

Comment: Beware that if `65:3.0` is the last field, you'll also get the trailing newline printed.

Comment: @user000001 no, unfortunately here strings add a trailing newline. Try it: `var=1:3.0,2:3.0,65:3.0; awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{print $2}' <<< "$var"`. How do you add a newline in `RS`? I tried `RS=$',\n'` but, unsurprisingly it doesn't work.

Comment: Of course this works (or in bashier style with a process substitution). So this can't be done with `awk`? you can't have several record separators?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Why not like this: `var=1:3.0,2:3.0,65:3.0; printf '%s' "$var" | awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{printf "%s\n", $2}'`. Or if you want multiple separators like this `awk -F: -v RS=',|\n' '$1==65{print $2}' <<< "$var"`

Comment: Oh thanks, I overlooked the `|` in record separators! nice to know.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes RS is a regex (at least in GNU awk)

Comment: Actually you could force a trailing comma: `<<< "$var,"`. `:)`.

Comment: You could just use a character list `RS='[,\n]'`. Again that's gawk-only for multi-char RS.

Comment: @EdMorton do you see an advantage for the character list? I find the other syntax more readable as it looks more like an "or"...

Comment: It's probably more efficient but IMHO it's just briefer, clearer, and more easily extensible: `[abcd]` vs `a|b|c|d`. It's what character lists exist to do.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure Bash solution:

```
var=10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0

while read -r -d, i; do
    [[ $i = 65:* ]] || continue
    echo "$i"
done <<< "$var,"
```

You may use `break` after `echo "$i"` if there's only one `65:...` in `var`, or if you only want the first one.

To get the value `3.0`: `echo "${i#*:}"`.

---

Other (pure Bash) approach, without parsing the string explicitly. I'm assuming you're only looking for the first `65` in the string, and that it is present in the string:

```
var=10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0

value=${var#*,65:}
value=${value%%,*}
echo "$value"
```

This will be very slow for long strings!

---

Same as above, but will output all the values corresponding to `65` (or none if there are none):

```
var=10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0

tmpvar=,$var
while [[ $tmpvar = *,65:* ]]; do
    tmpvar=${tmpvar#*,65:}
    echo "${tmpvar%%,*}"
done
```

Same thing, this will be slow for long strings!

---

The fastest I can obtain in pure Bash is my original answer (and it's fine with 10000 fields):

```
var=10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0

IFS=, read -ra ary <<< "$var"
for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
    [[ $i = 65:* ]] || continue
    echo "$i"
done
```

---

In fact, no, the fastest I can obtain in pure Bash is with this regex:

```
var=10:3.0,16:4.0,32:4.0,39:2.0,65:3.0,95:4.0,110:4.0,111:4.0,2312:1.0

[[ ,$var, =~ ,65:([^,]+), ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

---

Test of this vs `awk`,

- where the `65:3.0` is at the end:

  ```
  printf -v var '%s:3.0,' {100..11000}
  var+=65:42.0
  time awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{print $2}' <<< "$var"
  ```

  shows 0m0.020s (rough average) whereas:

  ```
  time { [[ ,$var, =~ ,65:([^,]+), ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; }
  ```

  shows 0m0.008s (rough average too).
- where the `65:3.0` is not at the end:

  ```
  printf -v var '%s:3.0,' {1..10000}
  time awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{print $2}' <<< "$var"
  ```

  shows 0m0.020s (rough average) and with early exit:

  ```
  time awk -F: -v RS=',' '$1==65{print $2;exit}' <<< "$var"
  ```

  shows 0m0.010s (rough average) whereas:

  ```
  time { [[ ,$var, =~ ,65:([^,]+), ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; }
  ```

  shows 0m0.002s (rough average).

Comment: This is probably the best solution for small strings, as it avoids spawning a new process like the awk/sed answers do. However, the OP mentions that the string could be *very long*, so storing it all in an array could lead to unnecessary memory usage.

Comment: @user000001 We don't have the OP's definition of very long `:)`. Sure, for several megabytes of data this is not the best approach. But the string is already stored in a Bash variable, so I think it's going to be ok.

Comment: I think it is an excellent solution. The maximum length of string may be 10000 key-value pairs. I will try.

Comment: @user000001 I highly doubt if this would be more efficient than an awk or sed solution for long strings, and for short strings the difference in speed of execution doesn't matter unless this is in a loop that iterates a huge number of times, but then you'd really need to question the whole approach.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry Ed, but `awk` is not at all the most efficient. `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Not a fair comparison. Try with `'$1==65{print $2;exit}'`

Comment: @user000001 this won't make a difference when the 65 is at the end of the string. If it's at the front, it's still slower.

Comment: I said that the difference in speed for small files would be negligible and you showed that it is (the blink of an eye vs a slight faster blink of an eye - 10ms vs 2ms). You changed your shell loop answer to a regexp answer due to it being slow but did not test it against an awk regexp answer so you are in no way comparing apples to apples. Either test your original shell loop against the original awk solution you have, or test an awk regexp solution against your new shell regexp solution. IMHO you should just test with the target 65 value being in the middle of the string.

Comment: @EdMorton how would you do this with a regex in `awk`?

Comment: In GNU awk you could do `awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/(^|.*,)65:([^,]+).*/,"\\2","",var)}'`. In other awks you could use a couple of sub()s or a match()+substr() and I expect the time would be about the same. I'd be most interested in seeingthe results of the shell loop answer since my usual assertion is that if you're using a shell loop to manipulate text then you have the wrong approach but obviously whatever you think is useful since you're the guy testing it....

Comment: @EdMorton this one is even slower: 0m0.035s.

Comment: @EdMorton the loop is awfully slow (and you're absolutely right about the idea of loops being wrong): it's about 0m150s.

Comment: OK, good to know that a regexp match against a shell variable in shell is faster than a regexp match against a shell variable in awk but a loop in shell is slower than a loop in awk and that the fastest shell solution ran in 2ms while the fastest awk solution ran in 10ms so both run in the blink of an eye. Thanks for testing.

Comment: BASHREMATCH answer doesn't work for me. I get `syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token \`('`. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Jidder: could be a typo or your bash version or cosmic rays. I'm not psychic, though very willing to help!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Can exclude a typo as it was c+p, i was thinking it was probably the version of bash, i'm using `GNU bash, version 3.1.17`. Can't rule out cosmic rays though!

Comment: @Jidder yeah, it seems there are problems with Bash 3.1 (though I could have it work with 3.0 and 3.2). To fix this: either escape the parentheses: `[[ ,$var, =~ ,65:\([^,]+\), ]]` or use a variable for the regex: `re=",65:([^,]+),"; [[ ,$var, =~ $re ]]`. Definitely not cosmic rays.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
echo $var | tr , '\n' | awk '/65/'
```

where

- `tr , '\n'` turn comma to new line
- `awk '/65/'` pick the line with 65

or

```
echo $var | tr , '\n' | awk -F: '$1 == 65 {print $2}'
```

where

- `-F:` use : as separator
- `$1 == 65` pick line with 65 as first field
- `{ print $2}` print second field

Comment: You can also avoid the `tr` call by setting the record separator with the `RS` variable.

Comment: @user000001 Is that standard awk feature ? I didn't know about it.

Comment: Yea, it works everywhere I have tried. Note that if you want a multi-character record separator you need GNU awk though.

Comment: the first solution would fail if a number like 165 appeared before 65 on the line. The second one is the same as posted by @user000001 in approach but less efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an  `gnu awk`

```
awk -vRS="(^|,)65:" -F, 'NR>1{print $1}' <<< "$var"
3.0
```

Comment: Try this `awk -vRS='^65:|,65:' -F, '$1!~/:/{print $1}' <<< "$var"`

Comment: No need for repetition of the number: `RS='(^|,)65:'`.

Answer (score 3):

With grep:

```
grep -o '\b65\b[^,]*' <<<"$var"
65:3.0
```

Or

```
grep -oP '\b65\b:\K[^,]*' <<<"$var"
3.0
```

`\K` option ignores everything before matched pattern and ignore pattern itself. It's Perl-compatibility(`-P`) for `grep` command .

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
sed -e 's/^.*,\(65:[0-9.]*\),.*$/\1/' <<<",$var,"
```

**output:**

```
65:3.0
```

There are two different ways to protect against `65:3.0` being the **first-in-line** or **last-in-line**. Above, `commas` are added to surround the variable providing for an occurrence regardless. Below, the Gnu extension `\?` is used to specify **zero-or-one** occurrence.

```
sed -e 's/^.*,\?\(65:[0-9.]*\),\?.*$/\1/' <<<$var
```

Both handle `65:3.0` regardless of where it appears in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try egrep like below:

```
echo $myvar | egrep -o '\b65:[0-9]+.[0-9]+' |
```